# How to view table data in the newest 6.0 MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I basically fail to view data in the new Workbench version without firing queries. I recall it was clearly possible in the previous version by simply using context menu something like "view table data".

Now in 6.0 I can't see this option anymore. Though I can see "search table data" which gives me next window where I have to input some mysterial query the pattern of which I fail to recognize. (see second screenshot - Start Search button is disabled)

[image]

[image]

It is not a big problem for me to fire queries, but still this is quite annoying especially if you don't see sql on daily basis using ORM and you just want to take a quick look at the table.

Oracle update - 1, :-)

My apologies to all db evangelists.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to see the data in a table then do a select for that table in a query editor. That's the most basic operation wrt SQL. Using the table search with some "mysterious query" certainly does not help to accomplish that task. Search is, as the name implies, a search. Put the value you are looking for in the search field and let MySQL Workbench do the search for you. As easy as that.

If you want a mouse only approach then open the schema in the tree and right click on the table you want to see. A context menu appears and the first entry is the select (which takes the limit into account that is set in the preferences, to avoid pulling a potential million rows).

[image]

The old "Edit table data" was a very similar shortcut, but that uses the EDIT keyword to tell the editor that the result is editable. That was an intermediate addition as MySQL Workbench had no other way to know if that is the case. In the meantime the application can detect this automatically (a PK must exist, no aggregates, no joins etc.), so the EDIT keyword as well as the shortcut have been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your table and choose select rows (first option)

Comment: i dont see my table, just query window

Answer (score 0):

Open a new SQL script file
There are 10 icons below
just click on the 5th icon labeled 'EXECUTE THE PLAIN COMMAND...……………..
and a second tab shows up
go to the right side of the screen and click on GRID RESULT

Comment: thank you so much for this! it was driving me NUTS. I up-voted, which brought the tally up to "0". wish it were higher ... I had a heck of time finding this view

Comment: I take it back. I'm can't get the result grid to consistently display and this tool is proving useless to me if I can't view results.